# How to improve this php mysql code?

Tags: php, mysql

With these codes I echo `Rank` of a student whose `regd` is equal to `$regd`. In fact, this is a working code. However, I was advised by a friend that in mysql statement `Distinct` and `Group By` should not be used together. But as a newbie, I could not figure out how I would implement it without using `Distinct` because it does not return rows without `Distinct`. Can anyone suggest me how I improve these codes?

```
<?php 
mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
$query_myrank = "SELECT Distinct regd, Name_of_exam, 
                        Name_of_Student, TOTALSCORE, Rank 
                 FROM (SELECT *, IF(@marks = (@marks := TOTALSCORE), 
                              @auto, @auto := @auto + 1) AS Rank 
                       FROM (SELECT Name_of_Student, regd, 
                                   Name_of_exam, SUM(Mark_score) AS TOTALSCORE 
                             FROM cixexam, (SELECT @auto := 0, 
                                                   @marks := 0) AS init 
                                            GROUP BY regd 
                             ORDER BY TOTALSCORE DESC) t) AS result 
                 HAVING (Name_of_exam='First Terminal Exam' OR 
                         Name_of_exam='First Term Test')";

$myrank = mysql_query($query_myrank, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());

$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$data = array();
while($row_myrank = mysql_fetch_assoc($myrank))
{
    $data[$i] = $row_myrank;
    if(isset($data[$i - 1]) 
           && $data[$i - 1]['TOTALSCORE'] == $data[$i]['TOTALSCORE'])
    {
       $data[$i]['Rank'] = $j;
    }else{
       $data[$i]['Rank'] = ++$j;
    }
       $i++;
}
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    if($value['regd'] == $regd)
    {
        echo $value['Rank'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I've heavily edited your query formatting, but it was SO messy that I might have indented it wrong. Please take a look at it and fix it if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distinct` is slower than `Group By`. You can go like this without using `Group By` and `Distinct` together and this could be what you want to achieve.

```
SELECT regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Name_of_exam,
       TOTALSCORE, Rank 
FROM 
(
  SELECT t.*, IF(@p = TOTALSCORE, @n, @n := @n + 1) AS Rank, @p := TOTALSCORE 
    FROM
  (
    SELECT regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Name_of_exam, 
            SUM(Mark_score) TOTALSCORE
    FROM cixexam, (SELECT @n := 0, @p := 0) n 
     WHERE (Name_of_exam='First Terminal Exam' OR Name_of_exam='First Term Test')
     GROUP BY regd 
     ORDER BY TOTALSCORE DESC
  ) t
) r
```

Comment: I have just tested your code in sql fiddle and it is working great. But the rank rows come like `[BLOB - 1B]` in phpmyadmin, what could have caused it? Is there anything wrong with my phpmyadmin?

Comment: I can echo what I want. You save my life. Thank you. But I don't know whether the BLOB-01 will cause me a problem in future, so I waill ask another question on that.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are [no longer maintained](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and the community has begun [the deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).

Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, this article [will help to choose](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

If you want to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: As valid as this is, I wouldn't count this as an answer to his question.