# Why am I getting [BLOB - 1B] in mysql rows?

Tags: mysql

This question is based on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859234/how-to-improve-this-php-mysql-code).
I was given an alternative to my code. I also accepted the code, as I can echo what I want properly. The problem is that when I run the sql code in sqlfiddle, everything is fine. But when I run the same code in phpmyadmin, I get [BLOB-1B] in the rank column rows. I have Googled and searched for an explanation, but I could not find suitable ones. So I want to know whether this is OK or not. Will it be causing an error in future? Any Help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the schema and the query.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. But I just want to know whether this will cause problem when output using php.

Comment: If you want to know if it will cause a problem when using PHP, try it using PHP.

Comment: @BarmarWhen output using php, it does seem fine. Thanks for your time.